# 2 External monitors on 21,5 iMac Late 2009?

Tags: display, imac, thunderbolt, hdmi, displayport

So I wonder if I can use 2 external monitors on my Late 2009 21,5 iMac?
I currently use 1 external monitor and it works great but I now want to sell it and use 2 external monitors but there is only one thunderbolt display output.

Is there a thunderbolt display adapter that has 2 HDMI's or 2 VGA outputs that would work for my device? Please, send links if you find one that works.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The late 2009 iMac uses Mini DisplayPort and **not** Thunderbolt, although they appear similar and share the same connector. The mDP technology included on the 2009 iMac does not support multiple displays.

In short, no. You will only be able to actually drive one monitor from the iMac, barring using a splitter. Such devices do exist but may not be able to provide you with a full dual-desktop experience (such as mirroring only, lower resolution, maximum display size limits, etc).

[Source on Specs](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT201994)